# How to use JQuery Datatables to show anonymous types?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

After obtaining the dynamic object and converting it to Json using the following code:

```
dynamic realTimeData = db.Database.DynamicSqlQuery("exec QueryRealTimeData @treeId", new SqlParameter("@treeId", treeId));

int draw = Request["draw"] != null ? int.Parse(Request["draw"]) : 1;

var jsonDataTemp = new {
  data = realTimeData,
    draw = draw
};

return Json(jsonDataTemp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

It was found that the Json format of the transformation (format 1 below) was not the format I needed:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "B01-Rtd": 10.285,
    "001-Rtd": 7.522,
    "011-Rtd": 20.903
  }, {
    "B01-Rtd": 10.031,
    "001-Rtd": 7.518,
    "011-Rtd": 20.903
  }],
  "draw": 1
}
```

I actually need to convert to the following format (format 2) for the data source for the JQuery DataTables:

```
[{
  "COLUMNS": [
    {"title": "B01-Rtd"},
    {"title": "001-Rtd"},
    {"title": "011-Rtd"}
  ],
  "DATA": [
    ["10.285", "7.522", "20.903"],
    ["10.031", "7.518", "20.903"]
  ],
  "draw": 1
}]
```

Ask how to convert to format 2, or how to use format 1 data to the DataTables data source?

Note I this is dynamically generated anonymous objects, don't know in advance what columns, without explicitly initialize column, need to be dynamically generated similar two Json format, and then use similar to the following JS initialization DataTables:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "data": dataObject[0].DATA,
  "columns": dataObject[0].COLUMNS
});
```

Or are there other ways to display anonymous types with Datatables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var dataObject = [{
  "data": [{
    "B01-Rtd": 10.285,
    "001-Rtd": 7.522,
    "011-Rtd": 20.903
  }, {
    "B01-Rtd": 10.031,
    "001-Rtd": 7.518,
    "011-Rtd": 20.903
  }],
  "draw": 1
}];

var data = [],
  columns = [];

if (dataObject.length && dataObject[0].data.length) {
  columns = Object.keys(dataObject[0].data[0]).map(x => {
    return {
      title: x
    }
  });
  
  dataObject[0].data.forEach((item, index) => {
    var values = [];
    columns.forEach(x => { 
      values.push(item[x.title]);
    });
    data.push(values);
  });
}
console.log(columns);
console.log(data);

//$('#example').dataTable({
//  "data": data,
//  "columns": columns
//});
```